# Docker daemon inactive (dead)

Tags: docker, daemon, open-source, docker-machine

I am having trouble with my Portainer GUI. I can't seem to find my local environment. As a solution, I changed some parameters in the 'docker.socket' file on my Ubuntu server. However, this seems to have caused some issues with my docker setup and now I am unable to start it. I am still new to this and would appreciate some help before I give up.

Here is my current status:

`systemctl docker.socket`

```
○ docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit docker.socket has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
   Triggers: ● docker.service

Mar 05 18:19 linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket:6: Failed to parse address value in 'var/run/docker.sock', ignoring: Invalid argument
Mar 05 18:19 linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit has no Listen setting (ListenStream=, ListenDatagram=, ListenFIFO=, ...). Refusing.
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: and it tells you right away, to verify the situation in the file. the file has no listen directive. please read carefully [ask] and update the question with the required and nessescary information.